# Are there ways to use 何様, other than in 何様だと思いますか or なにさまのつもりですか？

Tags: words

Jisho says "absolutely; certainly; to be sure(adverb)," but I don't think I've EVER seen it used that way

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%95%E6%A7%98/ - the examples for the non-'Who do you think you are?' type meanings sound pretty old so it's a safe bet it's archaic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen it used that way, either, but according to three monolingual dictionaries I checked, this type of 何様 seems to be an adverb meaning "indeed", "true, ...", "admittedly" or "to be sure" rather than "absolutely". It's interchangeable with いかにも, なるほど, たしかに, etc. Here are examples quoted in dictionaries:

- **何様**そんなこともあるだろう
  Indeed, something like this might happen.
- **何様**近来に稀れなる一珍事なり (南洋の大波瀾; 1891)
  This is certainly a rare event in recent years.
- 貧相に見えるが、**何様**一の政治家には違ひない (雪中梅; 1886)
  He looks poor, but he still is one politician, anyway.

You can practically forget this usage unless you're reading old materials.